# Reading contents from current EPUB rendition view in React-Native

Tags: react-native, epub, epub.js

I'm trying to do some stuff using react-native and epubjs-rn but I'm facing some problems.

After loading the book on the app, I want to get the text or xhtml that's being currently displayed on the view. In AngularJS with the usual epubjs I could do it using the renditions.view() method.

But, from what I understand right now, I can't get whats on the rendition like that with epubjs-rn, since there's no view() method. Is there any way possible to get the contents of a view/ebook as some sort of xhtml/html structurer?

Right now I really don't know if it's possible in react-native.

Here's the github page for the epub library I'm trying to use: https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn

Thanks in Advance